# How to databind images from the media library to a listbox?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, listbox, windows-phone-7.1, media-library

I want to bind a ListBox with images from the media library.

Till now i have done this but it doesn't seem to work :

xaml code:

```
<ListBox Name="pictureHolder" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" 
                 Width="445" Margin="0,417,12,26"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Name="imageFile" Source="{Binding Picture}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

cs code:

```
private void bindPictures()
    {
        pictureHolder.ItemsSource = library.Pictures;
    }
```

What's wrong with the code??
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try searching msdn
its got whole article about it